# FindFit giving errors

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have this data

```
data = 
  {{1992.22, -6.4}, {1994.31, -28.5}, {1995.53, -37.3}, {1996.25,-43.4}, {1996.43, -45.9}, 
   {1997.54, -59.}, {1998.37, -65.3},{1999.47, -67.5}, {2000.47, -55.3}, {2000.52, -62.8}}
```

I would like to fit data with the function `(((-0.7549279861772439*x) + (0.40687*y))/8.3)` coming from the model:

```
M = (4.3*10^6)+1;G=4pi^2M
model[q_?NumberQ] := 
  (model[q] = First[(((-0.7549279861772439*x) + (0.40687*y))/8.3) 
/. NDSolve[{(G M x[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + 
M (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] ==0, (G M y[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 
+y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + M (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0, x[1992.22] == 888,x'[1992.22] == 147, 
y[1992.22] == 1560, y'[1992.22] == 25}, {x, y}, {t, 1992.22, 2000.52}, Method -> 
{StiffnessSwitching,  Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
PrecisionGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]);

fit = 
  FindFit[
    data, 
    model[q][(((-0.7549279861772439*x) + (0.40687*y))/8.3)], {{q, 10^-15}}, (((-0.7549279861772439*x) + (0.40687*y))/8.3), 
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 15]
```

But I have the error message:

> General::ivar: "0.120482\ (-0.754928\ x+0.40687\ y) is not a valid variable."

Any suggestion?

EDIT 1:

Trying with variable initial conditions:

```
parsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(G M x[
     t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
       2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + 
 M x''[t] == 
0, (G M y[
     t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/
       2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + 
 M y''[t] == 0, x[1992.22] == x0, x'[1992.22] == vx,
```

y[1992.22] == y0, y'[1992.22] == vy}, {x, y}, {t, 1992.22, 
   2009.61}, {q, x0, vx, y0, vy}]

```
ClearAll[model]
model[q_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ, vx_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, 
vy_?NumericQ, 
t_?NumericQ] := ((-0.7549279861772439*#1 + 0.40687*#2)/8.3) & @@ 
Through[parsol[q, x0, vx, y0, vy][t]]
fit = FindFit[data, 
model[q, x0, vx, y0, vy, 
t], {{q, 10^15}, {x0, 888}, {vx, 137}, {y0, 1550}, {vy, 25}}, t]
```

I have this error:

> Input expression ParametricFunction[<>] contains insufficient information 
>        to interpret the result. >>

I would expect q near to 1, but it seems this is wrong.

Comment: Your code has some problems. `StiffnessSwitching` and `ExplicitRungeKutta` should be strings but you're missing quotes. You have things like `x^\[Prime]\[Prime][t]` in there too which should be just `x''[t]`

Comment: Your data set has only 2 variables while you need 3 for what you propose:  1 response and 2 predictors.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few syntax and construction problems here. First `pi` should be `Pi`. Then you are trying to find the best value for the parameter q, so the appropriate family of diffeq solvers for this is `ParametricNDSolve`, which gives you a solution depending on an unknown value of a parameter, e.g. `q` in your case.

Some of your derivatives were also written as powers, e.g. `(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])`, but they should be should be `y''` instead.

```
(*Note Pi, not pi*)
M = 4.3*10^6 + 1; 
G = 4 Pi^2 M;

(* The parametric solver *)
parsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
          {(G M x[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + M x''[t] == 0, (G M y[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + M y''[t] == 0, x[1992.22] == 888, x'[1992.22] == 147, y[1992.22] == 1560, y'[1992.22] == 25}, 
          {x, y}, {t, 1992.22, 2000.52}, {q}
         ]
```

I have also removed the method selections within the solver (which should have specified as strings anyway). I always recommend starting with the default values to make sure the approach works, at least. Only if the default methods are not satisfactory would I then start digging into method issues.

Then your model function depends on the value of $q$ and $t$ to internally produce a single value that depends on `x[t]` and `y[t]`:

```
ClearAll[model]
model[q_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := ((-0.7549279861772439*#1 + 0.40687*#2)/8.3) & @@ Through[parsol[q][t]]
```

Finally, with these in hand, it is straightforward to use the fitting function:

```
fit = FindFit[data, model[q, t], {{q, 10^-15}}, t]

(* Out: {q -> -7.22547*10^-14} *)
```

---

Here is a version with more flexibility, which includes the starting conditions as parameters:

```
(*The parametric solver with modifiable starting conditions*)
parsol = Block[{t0, tmax},
  {t0, tmax} = MinMax@data[[All, 1]];
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{
     (G M x[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + M x''[t] == 0, 
     (G M y[t])/((x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2) (1 + (6 G M q)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2])^(1/3)) + M y''[t] == 0, 
     x[t0] == x0, x'[t0] == xprime0, y[t0] == y0, y'[t0] == yprime0}, 
     {x, y}, {t, t0, tmax}, {q, x0, y0, xprime0, yprime0}]
  ]

ClearAll[model]
model[q_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, 
      x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, 
      xprime0_?NumericQ, yprime0_?NumericQ] := 
          ((-0.7549279861772439*#1 + 0.40687*#2)/8.3) & @@ Through[parsol[q, x0, y0, xprime0, yprime0][t]]

fit = FindFit[data, model[q, t, 888, 1560, 147, 25], {{q, 10^-15}}, t]
```

Comment: Thank you! pi was a typos but i was wrong in the definition of the model

Comment: In this way can I add other parameters? For example initial conditions

Comment: Ok, now I edit the question. In reality I would expect a best fit value for q near to 1, but with the given initial conditions I can''t find it.

Comment: @Orion take a look at the edit

Comment: But if I replace {t0, tmax} with {1992.22, 2009.61} I get the error message:  Local variable specification {1992.22`,2009.61`} contains 1992.22`, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol. >>

Comment: @Orion That replacement would not make sense. You could replace `{t0, tmax} = {1992.22, 2009.61}` if you want, but note that this is exactly what the `MinMax` code accomplishes anyway. What were you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to have variable initial conditions, but I thought that {t0,tmax} should be fixed to compare solution with the data. If I leave unchanged as you wrote I get: Lists {t0,tmax} and MinMax[{1992.22,1994.31,1995.53,1996.25,1996.43,1997.54,1998.37,1999.47,2000.47,2000.52,2001.5,2002.49,2002.25,2002.34,2002.39,2002.41,2002.41,2002.41,2002.58,2002.66,2002.66,2003.21,2003.35,2003.36,2003.45,2003.45,2003.45,2003.45,2003.45,2003.55,2003.68,2003.68,2003.76,2004.24,2004.33,2004.35,2004.44...5,<<20>>}] are not the same shape. >>